# Get json with tweets from twitter timeline

Tags: java, json, twitter

In order to bypass the rate limits from Twitter API, I'm creating a project to get old tweets through JSON.

Right now I'm using this type URL to get JSON from a specific user (let that user be LeoDiCaprio):

https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=from%3ALeoDiCaprio&src=typd&max_position=null

The problem is: There is some tweets missing in this JSON.

Like this one: https://twitter.com/LeoDiCaprio/status/695354090943967232

You can easily look in his timeline and check that every tweets he posted before are present in the JSON. But some tweets are missing, like that one.

I have no idea why. So, how the browser get those tweets (including the missing ones)? Anyone knows how I can find the correct, if any, URL?

Thanks!